# Why Doesn't Hibernate Just Shut Down Without Clearing the RAM

Tags: memory, shutdown, hibernate

Most people know that RAM memory is cleared when shutting down a computer. Since RAM is a type of memory/storage, why can't we just keep everything in the RAM, and shutdown without clearing it. Therefor, when the computer turns on, it doesn't take a good ten seconds to read a few gigabytes of data from the hard drive, and push it into RAM. This would be much faster, and not require swap partitions or pagefiles.

Comment: RAM requires power to maintain its contents. No power = No data.

Comment: Oh.... So this is what sleep is, except it only powers RAM?

Comment: Yes, more or less. its a great deal more complicated, but in essence you are right. With the possible exception of cold boot exploits, unless the ram image gets stored to disk (windows puts it in hiberfil.sys), it will be lost when the machine loses power.

Comment: There are different [sleep states](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/153968-sleep-states-see-available-sleep-states.html), but RAM remains powered except in S5 (which is shutdown).

Comment: Because as you said.  Memory is cleared when the machine is shutdown, and hibernate, dumps the memory to disk and then the system is turned off.  What you describe is called `sleep` proper research is required to ask good questions.

Comment: @DavidPostill -- Not every type of RAM is volatile (i.e. requires power to maintain data).  Ferrite core memory will retain data when powered off.

Comment: *"RAM memory is cleared when shutting down..."* -- There is no such explicit operation of *"clearing RAM"*.  Volatile memory simply loses the data after power off.

Comment: @sawdust Yes, I know. I was trying to keep things simple. Ferrite core is not normally used in PCs ;)

Comment: @sawdust is Ferrite core memory supported by the authors hardware though?

Comment: @Ramhound -- The OP only mentions a *"computer"*. The point is that volatility (or not) is not an intrinsic attribute of RAM. The definition for "RAM" does not specify that it must be volatile.  *"RAM is volatile"* seems to be a common/widespread misconception among PC users, but that is not a true statement.  If you want to refer to the typical RAM in PCs with respect to its volatility, then the better term to use is DRAM, i.e. "DRAM requires power (and refresh) to maintain its contents".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure can. That is called '**Sleep Mode**'.

It uses a small amount of power, as the memory needs power to remember the content. if you want to have no power usage, you need to put the content on a non-volatile place, which is the hard disk, and it takes a moment to write it there.

Comment: It could be a better answer if it mentioned S3 power mode and difference between S1 and S3 IMO.